# C++Builder Force a special file to be compiled

Tags: c++, compilation, c++builder

In our sources we have a datamodule in which certain standard values are set (such as Build number including compiling date). This module should always be compiled. How can we force this in the C++ Builder without always compiling all the modules or manually 'Touche' the module so it is marked as changed?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add the filename to *Project Options -> C++ Compiler -> Advanced -> Additional options to pass to compiler*. You can literally write the filename there, for example `System.cpp`. However, the file is recompiled only when some C++ file in the project has changed, not when you Make with no changes.

Drawback is that when the file is changed manually, it will be added to the command line twice, and there is a warning: `[bcc32c Warning] ignoring duplicated input file 'System.cpp' [-Wborland]`. To get rid of this, you can exclude the file from build (right click the file).

Comment: Thanks for your respond. The module is now always recompiled. What is not so nice is that it looks if the C++Builder also marks the header file as changed. This causes all modules in which this is included to be recompiled. Do you have a tip for me how to prefent this?

Comment: @user7579346 Use different filename for header and cpp file.

Comment: Hello I found out that it didn't work. In first instance it looked if it works but it didn't. I treid to put it as value for all configurations - all Plattform but it didn't add it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Build Events](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Build_Events) dialog box to specify a *pre-build event* command:

[image: Build Event Commands]

Deleting the corresponding object (`.obj`) file or [touching](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/TOUCH.EXE) the source should be enough.

Comment: Thanks but how to touch a file without changing it? Touch doesn't exist under dos.

Comment: @PaulHoefakker Among the C++Builder command line utilities there is [touch.exe](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/TOUCH.EXE). I'm not sure if the utility folder is added to the system path during the RAD Studio installation.

Comment: Hello Manlio, in our installation it isn't there. We are working with the C++Builder 10.2

Comment: Hello Manlio, I found the exe. It is only not show in the Pre-Build Makros. Thanks

Comment: The Touch command is executed after the C++builder has determined which files have to be compiled. So it doesn't compile the touched file but afterwards its told the file has changed :-(

Comment: Now I placed it in the Post-Build Event. Means the first time it doesn't work but afterwards it does.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. With the C++Builder a small Tool is delivered 'Touch' This tool can be used to make sure a module is always compiled. It must be added in the project options under Build events (I'm not sure the option is called like this. Only know the german description 'Build Ereignisse' which I translated) The file I want to be compiled always is called 'DmFehlerF.cpp' in directory 'edi'. To get this I added in the Post build events as commant 'Touch -c .\edi\DmFehlerF.cpp'
[Projectoptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwZmf.png)